# C# Win. Form - Optimizing code to change color of 20,000 individual row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i have a datagridview which populates 20,000 rows and ***Yes i need all of them to be displayed at once because if i load a part of it then the report isn't useful at all***.

Now getting the records takes about **1.5 to 2 seconds** which is rational because of the large number but after fetching the record i have to individually change every row's color on meeting a specific case like in my case if that record has a column "**Iden=0**" then change the color to "**Light Grey**" for which is use the following code.

```
//Datagridview Has 20,000 Records in it
for (int i = 0; i < dgvItem.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (dgvItem.Rows[i].Cells["Iden"].EdittedFormattedValue.ToString() == "0")
    {
         dgvItem.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGrey;
    }
}
```

but using the above code it takes about 10-12 seconds. Now is there any way to optimize it?

I have tried using "**SuspendLayout**" and "**ResumeLayout**" but that was useless.

Comment: I am not sure, but may be you can try change the color of the row in RowPostPaint/RowPrePaint events

Comment: @VDN you seem to miss the point. "dgvItem.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGrey;" this statement is taking time to execute 20K times and that is why i am asking for an alternative.

Comment: I understand it correctly, and I think using RowPostPaint should work fast. As I understand, the event RowPostPaint is called only for the rows that are currently visible on the screen, so it will not execute 20K

Comment: Have you tried creating the datagridviewrows in memory, setting the back colour and only then adding them to the datagridview?

Comment: Have you considered looking into the [virtual mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) of the data grid view?

Comment: @bassfader this is another method i could have used but as the below one was simpler to implement i chose that one, still thanks for looking that up for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add to your datagrid an event like this:

```
private void dgvItem_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvItem.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Iden"].EditedFormattedValue.ToString() == "0")
    {
        dgvItem.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
    }
}
```

It has some flickering while scrolling the datagrid, but it fast enough, I believe.

Comment: To prevent flicker make the DGV Doublebuffered!

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this, I have had some performance improvements by suspending (and then resuming) drawing.  It requires a API call though:

```
        #region Suspend / resume drawing
    /// <summary>
    /// Method to stop drawing of the control (useful when doing data dumps etc)
    /// </summary>
    public void SuspendDrawing()
    {
        NativeMethods.SendMessage(this.Handle, NativeMethods.WM_SETREDRAW, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to restart drawing of the control if it has been stopped.
    /// </summary>
    public void ResumeDrawing()
    {
        NativeMethods.SendMessage(this.Handle, NativeMethods.WM_SETREDRAW, (IntPtr)1, (IntPtr)0);
        this.Refresh();
    }
    #endregion
```

And the Native Method:

```
internal static class NativeMethods
    {
        //Codes for suspending painting (for fast loading)
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        public static uint WM_SETREDRAW = 11;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i have already tried this sort of solution and after applying your code it take "0.025 seconds" more than before.